# What are must have reports/graphs in a test management software?

Tags: quality-assurance

I was wondering which reports and graphs are actually used by software testing teams.

Comment: https://www.qasymphony.com/blog/64-test-metrics/

Comment: It depends on who needs to read the reports.  Different managers/product owners/etc. would have different needs.

Answer (score 1):

There are no must-haves.  I would like to update your question to "What are useful..." if you wouldn't mind.

Useful reports and graphs would include statistics on:

- Number and type of test cases (features, bugs, etc.)
- Average time spend in the various statuses
- Overall velocity of time from test story initiation to completion
- Who's worked on what over time
- Planned vs actual for work done

Answer (score 0):

Another good chart is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burn_down_chart which gives obvious visual clue if project is on track.

I like addition which adds all unplanned but needed work at the bottom, to show how addition are delaying the release.